# Text input and submit input elements have different height in firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox

The code:

```
<input class="text" type="text" value="text"><input class="submit" type="submit" value="submit">
```

with styling:

```
.text, .submit {
    outline: none;
    border: none;
    padding: none;
    margin: none;
    background: red;
    padding: 3px;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

(https://jsfiddle.net/citizenfive/04camn42/)

creates 2 input elements with different heights (submit is larger by ~1px).

The code works fine on Chrome. Is there a way to solve this for Firefox?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All browsers have differences between default behaviours and styles, but firefox is more flexible with S.O. and form elements are controlled by default by the operating system.

The solution is remove padding or use height with EM meassures.

### Remove padding:

https://jsfiddle.net/04camn42/2/

```
 .class { padding: 0 }
```

### Using EM height:

https://jsfiddle.net/04camn42/3/

```
 .class {
     height: 1.5em
 }
```

IF you use EM you don't worry about responsiveness and user choices.

Comment: Great, this works. I can get my intended effect using height in em and left/right padding in em as well.

Comment: padding: none; margin: none;  - 
both should be "0" instead of "none" (  padding: 0; margin: 0;  )

Answer (score 0):

Removed padding and added height, this works fine in Chrome and Firefox but I don't know whether this fix is fine for you.

New css,

```
.text, .submit {
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  padding: none;
  margin: none;
  background: red;
  /* padding: 3px; */
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 23px;
}
```

Comment: This breaks if I (or the user) changes the font-size or padding so not ideal. Would prefer not to hard-code the height.

Answer (score 0):

In order to remove all padding and borders from buttons and inputs for Firefox this handy little CSS snippet will help you out.

```
button::-moz-focus-inner,
input::-moz-focus-inner {
  border: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

Also, what's been suggested by the other posters: use `box-sizing: border-box;` on all form elements to make them behave in all browsers (apart from Firefox).

Answer (score -1):

```
.text, .submit {
    outline: none;
    border: none;
    padding: none;
    margin: none;
    background: red;
    padding: 3px;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

see in i

Comment: This made no difference.